# EditorWindow : Input with recursive output error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, recursion, arraylist

Afternoon -> Mid-morning;  Basically I'm currently having an issue with IEquatable which is located in "Using System" and "Using System.Collection.Generic",  Basically what the purpose of this task is to have the user Select a database and send input;  I have them send the input through a basic string which I have tested and it works.  Although my issue is purely visual and also the data appears to be accumulating within the list; So what's happening {[image: HERE]} takes the last input string and copies it and sends it again and copies the last few inputs and sends them with the new input;  Which takes the previous functions and acts as if it's a recursion method which I personally wouldn't think it would be.
[image]

```
    internal class _Command : IEquatable<_Command>
{
    public string _SQLiteCOMMAND { get; set; }
    public int _SQLiteCOMMAND_CNT { get; set; }
    public override string ToString() { return "Command Number : " + _SQLiteCOMMAND_CNT + "\n  Command : " + _SQLiteCOMMAND; }
    public override int GetHashCode() { return _SQLiteCOMMAND_CNT; }
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null) return false;
        _Command CMD_OBJ = obj as _Command;
        if (CMD_OBJ == null) return false;
        else return Equals(CMD_OBJ);
    }
    public bool Equals(_Command ETC)
    {
        if (ETC == null) return false;
        return (this._SQLiteCOMMAND_CNT.Equals(ETC._SQLiteCOMMAND_CNT));
    }
}
```

Basically what I have done here is setup an IEquatable table that will hold my list instead of a generic new string list; which I have tried but I get a lesser and slower response.

```
  public void _SendQueryCOMMAND(int id)
{
    _Database.Add(new _Command() { _SQLiteCOMMAND = _ConsoleCommandInput, _SQLiteCOMMAND_CNT = _CMDval+1 });
    _ConsoleLoggerUpdate();
}
```

This is a snippet of how I send my Command to the database and it has an output that shows me What command number so if I send 3 commands It will say I have sent Commands "3" or in my personal term's "2";

```
 public void _ConsoleLoggerUpdate()
{
    foreach (_Command _SQLiteCommand in _Database)
    {
        _ConsoleCommandInput += _SQLiteCommand + "\n";
    }
}
```

This is how I format my data into the list is with a foreach statement that adds each formatted command into that list on a new line.

```
_ConsoleCommandWindow = EditorGUILayout.TextArea(_ConsoleCommandInput, GUILayout.Width(position.width - 5), GUILayout.Height(75));
```

This is how my data is formatted into a window as my Input Data

```
    public void _outputConsole(int id)
{
    GUILayout.Label("Current Input Text :" + _ConsoleCommandInput);
    GUILayout.Box("", new GUILayoutOption[] { GUILayout.ExpandWidth(true), GUILayout.Height(1) });

}
```

This would be how I have my information formatted for output

I have read and tried using Array's and Lists about at-least 50 different ways I could think of even by reading the documentation and following along even copying and pasting and trying to make it work I've always have had the same "recursive" problem that I'm presently having.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x303t819(v=vs.110).aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After tinkering for hours on end I ended up getting fustrated and starting from scratch.  I eneded up scrapping almost 2/3 of the work I've done for the past two days and actually ended up figuring out my error as I removed everything.

```
_CommandInputEntry = EditorGUILayout.TextField(_CommandInputEntry, GUILayout.Width(position.width - Screen.width / 2.25f), GUILayout.Height(75));
```

My Input error was all at the front of this as I tried to seperate the string and the formula from "_CommandInputWindow" to "_CommandInputEntry",  When both should have been one or the other completely.

```
if (GUILayout.Button("Send Command")) { _CommandListEntry.Add(_CommandInputEntry); _consoleWindowMethod(1); }
```

Instead of calling a complex formula or any type of method I ended up using a simple List and a pretty basic foreach statement,  Instead of having a complex calling system the moment you hit "Send Command", it adds the current Textile input and adds it to the list, and then calls the Method that will show the recent string into the list that would be the following input.

```
    public void _consoleWindowMethod(int id)
{
    foreach (string _command in _CommandListEntry)
    {
        GUILayout.Label("Command :" + _command);
        GUILayout.Box("", new GUILayoutOption[] { GUILayout.ExpandWidth(true), GUILayout.Height(1) }); // Divider
    }
}
```

This is actually how I ended up storing my list variables;  Ending up pretty  simple!

```
private List<string> _CommandListEntry = new List<string>();
```